# Manipulate html as string with jquery and update span content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to update content in an html string using jquery  :

```
var html = '<span class="spent_time">2.5 h</span><span class="planned_time">1.3 h</span>' ;
```

I'm trying to update the "planned_time" span with :

```
var $html = $(html) ;
```

And

```
$(html).find('.planned_time').html('3 h') ;
```

It doesnt work, obviously. What am I missing ?

Comment: What is `$html` or `$(html)` for that matter?

Comment: Vars - he defined them

Comment: missing var is just a typo. it's not the pb here

Comment: $html = "x" will create a variable in the global scope - `window["$html"]`

Comment: What is the intended outcome? Two `spans` with spent_time being `2.5 h` and planned_time being `3 h` instead of `1.3 h`?

Comment: yes exactly - i want to replace 1.3 h by 3 h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string needs a parent container to use find

If you are planning to insert the new HTML then update after:

```js
var html = '<span class="spent_time">2.5 h</span> <span class="planned_time">1.3 h</span>';
$("#d1").html(html); // insert it to show it

$('.planned_time').html('3 h'); // NOW update the span
```

```css
span { border: 1px solid black; padding:5px  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1"></div>
```

You can also wrap and update

```js
var $html = $('<div/>').html('<span class="spent_time">2.5 h</span> <span class="planned_time">1.3 h</span>');
$html.find(".planned_time").text("3 h"); // NOW you can update

$("#d1").append($html); // show it
```

```css
span { border: 1px solid black; padding:5px  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1"></div>
```

See other answer for a solution using filter.

Comment: _"You need to insert the html string somewhere"_ The HTML does not need to be inserted as HTML of an existing or dynamic element; the appropriate jQuery method needs to be used

Comment: @guest271314 that is interesting. I always wrapped to create a jquery container. I have not noticed the filter before

Comment: @mplungian `.filter()` traverses all elements within a jQuery object, `.find()` only traverses child nodes of a jQuery object

Answer (score 1):

Use `.filter()` instead of `.find()`; `.find()` traverses child nodes of a parent element - `.planned_time` is not a child node within HTML string

```js
var html = '<span class="spent_time">2.5 h</span><span class="planned_time">1.3 h</span>';

var content = $(html);

content.filter(".planned_time").html("3 h");

console.log($(content).filter(".planned_time").html());
// do stuff with `content` variable
$("body").append(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Actually `$.parseHTML()` is also not necessary, see updated post

Comment: thank you for the filter trick. much better than using a dummy wrapper

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong.

```
$html = $(html);
```

First you need to create and element and parse html from your string:

```
var html = $.parseHTML( str );
```

Then, append your new html to your document, lets say you have some `div` container with id `#container`:

```
var $container = $( "#container" );
$container.append( html );
```

You can read more about parsing html [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)

Comment: @mplungjan Because `.planned_time` is not a child node within the HTML string

Comment: Where is the `.innerHTML` of `".planned_time"` set at Answer?